# Can a liberty dropin app be configured to use a shared library?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

In Websphere Liberty Profile, if I have a dropin app, can it be configured to use a shared library? Or does the app need to be explicity declared in the server.xml file in order to use files from a shared library, e.g.:

```
    <webApplication id="myapp"
            location="/root/wlp/myapp.war"
            name="edacm-se">
            <classloader delegation="parentLast">
                    <privateLibrary>
                            <folder dir="/root/SharedLibDir" />
                    </privateLibrary>
            </classloader>
    </webApplication>
```

I'm asking because I have an automated job to copy the file into the dropins folder, and I want to understand whether this can continue if the war requires a shared library, or if I will need to overwrite the server.xml file to specify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the section on Global libraries in the IBM KnowledgeCenter topic on [shared libraries](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/cwlp_sharedlibrary.html).

Comment: In other words, "yes, but with some limitations".  OP might also consider a [configuration dropin file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_setup_dropins.html) for their application configuration rather than copying the application binary to the dropins folder.

Comment: Interesting.. looks like a global library could be one option, as well as configuration dropin files.. I'll have a look into it.. thanks for the info :)